# Issue in calling RestAPI in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In existing pipeline the REST API key values (client ID and client secret) are expired. So, I have generated new keys values. I am able to generate token and extract API data in Postman using new client id and client secret.
In ADF pipeline, I am giving the new key values to generate token. But when calling API the newly generated token is not working. It is giving me the below error.
Do I need to change anything else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Details Failure happened on ' Source side . ErrorCode RestSourceCallFailed , Type Microsoft.Data
> Transfer.Common.Shared.Hybrid DeliveryException , Message The
> HttpStatusCode 401 indicates failure .**

From the error message it seems to be a permission issue. please make sure that the service principal has enough permissions.

[image: ref1]

More information about **RestAPI Calling** in Azure Data Factory use below  **Reference** in which we have detailed information about

•   REST linked service using UI

•   Connector configuration details

•   AAD service principal authentication

•   API key authentication

•   Copy data from REST connector into Azure Data Lake Storage in JSON format using OAuth.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#how-to-use-this-solution-template